# Align text according to length of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

So I was working on embedding a text to pdf using the library [pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib) in node.js. What I want to do is to embed names to a white box in pdf and align them to center according the the length of a string. `firstPage.drawText` is the part to align the text correctly. What I need is an algorithm to align text according the length of the string. Here's what I've tried, thanks in advance

```
async function loadandModPDF(name, gender) {
    // Load a PDFDocument from the existing PDF bytes
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);
    pdfDoc.registerFontkit(fontkit);

    const contName = await pdfDoc.embedFont(nameBold);

    // Get the first page of the document
    const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
    const firstPage = pages[0];
    const textSize = 16;

    try {
        textWidth = contName.widthOfTextAtSize(name, textSize);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    // Get the width and height of the first page
    const { width, height } = firstPage.getSize();

    // Draw a string of text diagonally across the first page
    firstPage.drawText("John Doe" , {
        x: (width - textWidth) / 3.1,
        y: height - (textSize * 26),
        size: textSize,
        font: contName,
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0),
        rotate: degrees(0),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using `pdfkit`. It Aligns text according to length of string automatically

```
import * as PDFDocument from 'pdfkit'
import getStream from 'get-stream'

const pdf = {
  createPdf: async (text: string) => {
    const doc = new PDFDocument()
    doc.fontSize(10).text(text, 50, 50)
    doc.end()

    const data = await getStream.buffer(doc)
    let b64 = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64')
    return b64
  }
}

export default pdf
```